# Using Twitter Ads API to create a scheduled tweet

Tags: twitter

I have hard time organize API calls to Twitter Ads API in order to create a simple sponsored tweet and I would love to get someone's help on that problem.

I'm using the following sequence of API calls and probably there is something I am missing:

**1) I have the ad_account set as a variable**

**2) getting funding instruments for the account:**

GET https://ads-api.twitter.com/8/accounts/:account_id/funding_instruments

-- result --

```
{
    ...
    id: '11uze5', <---- THIS IS THE ID I'M STORING 
    entity_status: 'ACTIVE',
    account_id: '18ce55bxgcw',
    ...
}
```

**3) creating a campaign:**

POST https://ads-api.twitter.com/8/accounts/:account_id/campaigns

parameters:

```
{
    funding_instrument_id: THE ID I"M GETTING FROM THE PREVIOUS CALL
    name: "New Campaign 1",
    start_time: "2021-07-05T00:00:00Z",
    daily_budget_amount_local_micro: "140000000",
    entity_status: "PAUSED",
}
```

-- result ---

```
{
    ...
    name: 'New Campaign 1',
    id: 'f0ulq', <--- THIS IS THE ID I'M USING AS CAMPAIGN ID
    ...

}
```

**4) creating a line item into the newly created camapign:**

POST https://ads-api.twitter.com/8/accounts/:account_id/line_items

parameters:

```
{
    campaign_id: THE ID I"M GETTING FROM THE PREVIOUS CALL,
    objective: "WEBSITE_CLICKS",
    placements: "ALL_ON_TWITTER",
    product_type: "PROMOTED_TWEETS",
    entity_status: "PAUSED",
    bid_amount_local_micro: "3210000",
}
```

-- result --

```
{
    ...
    advertiser_user_id: 1326770328459227100
    name: 'Untitled'
    id: 'iocme', <-- THE ID I'M USING AS LINE ITEM ID
}
```

**5) uploading a file to be used as an image on the sponsored tweet (using media_category in order to get media_key parameter from the result)**
-- result --

```
{
    media_id: 1354065257501765600,
    media_id_string: '1354065257501765634',
    media_key: '3_1354065257501765634',
    size: 127727,
    expires_after_secs: 86400,
    image: { image_type: 'image/jpeg', w: 960, h: 637 },
}
```

**6) get authenticated users for the account**
GET https://ads-api.twitter.com/8/accounts/:account_id/authenticated_user_access

-- result --

```
{
    user_id: 1326770328459227100, <-- THIS IS THE USER ID I'M USING WHEN CREATING THE TWEET
    permissions: [ 'ACCOUNT_ADMIN', 'TWEET_COMPOSER' ]
}
```

**7) creating scheduled tweet**
POST https://ads-api.twitter.com/8/accounts/:account_id/scheduled_tweets

parameters:

```
{
    scheduled_at: "2021-02-01T23:59:00Z",
    text: "Scheduled tweet!",
    media_keys: MEDIA_KEY PARAMETER FROM THE UPLOADED MEDIA,
    as_user_id: 1326770328459227100 (THE USER ID FROM THE authenticated user's list)
}
```

**ERROR FROM TWITTER:**

```
    code: 'NOT_FOUND',
    message: 'Promotable User 1326770328459227100 was not found for Account 18ce55bxgcw'
```

So, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: There are two likely issues. The ID is being truncated or the authenticated user is not the FULL promotable user. The application should use the ID from https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/campaign-management/api-reference/promotable-users